# Calculating running time for C code

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-analysis, algorithms

The problem is this:

> How many array accesses does the following code fragment make as a function of $N$?
>
> ```
> int sum = 0;
> for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
>      for (int j = i+1; j < N; j++)
>          for (int k = 1; k < N; k = k*2)
>              if (a[i] + a[j] >= a[k]) sum++;
> ```

I'm supposed to discard lower order terms by using the tilde notation. For example, $$\large 2n^3 + 3n + 4 \rightarrow \text{~}2n^3$$

So I know the first loop runs $N$ times, but I don't know how many times the second and third run. So I can't know how many times the array access is made. How can I do this?

The explanation given was:

> Not all triple loops have cubic running times. For a given value of $i$ and $j$, the $k$-loop requires only $3 \lg N$ array access: the body is executed $\log N$ times and each time involves 3 array accesses. As in the 2-SUM and 3-SUM analysis, the number of times the $k$-loop is executed is $\binom{N}{2} \text{ ~ } \frac{1}{2} N^2$

> The full multiple choice answer was $\large\text{~ }\frac{3}{2}\lg N$

I don't understand the explanations either.

Comment: Starting from the outermost, we have that for each $i$ we get $N-i-1$ executions of the $j$ loop.  Since $i$ runs from $0$ to $N-1$, this is the same as getting $i$ executions of the $j$ loop for each $i$.  What is the count of such executions?  Since $k$ loops over the entire $0$ to $N-1$ number space, how does that factor in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The outer loop runs $N$ times. The middle loop runs a variable number of times each time the outer loop runs: from $1$ to $N-1$ (inclusive) when $i=1,$ but only once $(j=N-1)$ when $i=N-2$ and not at all when $i=N-1.$ on average it runs about $\frac 12 N$ times (minus a small constant). So altogether it runs $\sim\frac 12 N^2$ times. Within each of those loops, $k$ takes values $1, 2, 4, 8,$ and so forth until it reaches a power of $2$ that is $N$ or greater. That's $\sim\lg N$ different values of $k,$ and for each of those there are $3$ array accesses (on one line of code). So we multiply together $\sim\frac 12 N^2,$ $\sim\lg N,$ and $3.$ The result is $\sim\frac 32 N^2 \lg N.$

Comment: Isn't $1, 2, 4, 8$ like $2^x$ or something? Why do we use $\lg$?

Comment: The meaning of $\lg N$ is, "what power I have to raise $2$ to in order for the result to be $N$." For example, $\lg 64 = 6,$ because $2^6 = 64.$ So if $N=64,$ there will be $\lg 64=6$ different values of $k.$

Comment: How did you figure out that it runs $\frac{1}{2}N` times?

Comment: Well-known formula: $1 + 2 + 3 + \ldots N = \frac{N(N+1)}{2}.$ This sum only runs to $N - 1,$ which gives $\frac{(N-1)N}{2},$ but either of those formulas is $\sim\frac{N^2}{2}$ over all $N$ runs of the outer loop--a mean of $\sim\frac{N}{2}$ for each iteration of $i.$

Comment: Didn't you mean from $2$ to $N-1$ when $i=1$ because $j$ is equal to $i+1$?

Comment: Wait...I still don't get how you got from $\frac{N^2}{2}$ to $\frac{N}{2}$.

Comment: Perhaps I should have written the sum $(N-1)+(N-2)+\ldots+3+2+1,$ because the first value of $i$ is $i = 0,$ which results in $N-1$ iterations of the $j$ loop (from $j=1$ to $j=N-1$ inclusive), and the number of $j$-loop iterations _decreases_ as $i$ increases. But people usually write the sum in increasing order; and it adds up to the same value either way. Now, what is the _average_ value of all the integers from $1$ up to and including $N-1$? How many numbers are in that list, and what is their sum?

Comment: @DavidK I think the average would be $\frac{\sum_{j=1}^{N-1} j}{N-1} \rightarrow \frac{\frac{N(N-1)}{2}}{N-1}\rightarrow \frac{N(N-1)}{2(N-1)} \rightarrow \frac{N}{2}$ Right?

Comment: Yes, exactly. There's usually a lower-order term in these sums, but not in this case.